# Selenium unable to locate using any options of find element anchor tag which has no href, id

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Anchor tag has a space at end of text so I tried locating through Partial link text, even then it doesn't locate.

The `class` and `href` are present for many of the elements on the page

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ng-star-inserted">Add unit for monitoring </a>
```

which is under multiple `div` tags under app summary container.

> Tried xpath: `By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Add unit')]");`

> Partial link text: `By.partialLinkText("Add unit for monitoring");`

The page has 29 links but this has unique text still isn't locating in partial link text

Even tried scroll down as the element is at bottom of the page:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,350)", "");
```

None working, please help.

XPATH from browser shows:

```
//*[@id="root-container"]/app-home/clr-main-container/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/app-capacity-v2/div/app-edge-details-sddc/div/section[2]/app-tabs/app-edge-details-sddc-summary/section[2]/div/app-summary-container[4]/div/div/a
```

Comment: Check for the presence of `IFRAME`, if iframe doesn't exist try applying selenium's [waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: No iframe, it has section which has mutiple div tags.

Comment: try with XPATH of: //a[contains(text(),'Add unit')]

Comment: Yes working after extra wait.

Comment: But facing an issue on an anchor tag which is not getting clicked- which has space on both sides - which has absolute xpath:  
/html/body/app-root/div/app-home/clr-main-container/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/app-capacity-v2/div/app-capacity-container/div/div/section[2]/app-tabs/app-edge-list-v2/div/section[2]/app-grid/clr-datagrid/div[1]/div/div/div/div/clr-dg-row[1]/div/div[2]/div/clr-dg-cell[1]/a
I tried //a[normalize-space(text())='ename'] But the element is not getting clicked, just gets hovered. Please help